# dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (native)': native package version may not have a revision

Tags: debuild

I'm encountering this strange issue when using this [Launchpad recipe](https://code.launchpad.net/~the-warl0ck-1989/+recipe/xfce-appmenu-plugin-daily-1). The source package fails to build with this [error message in the buildlog](https://code.launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/experimental/+recipebuild/639755):

```
dpkg-source -i -I -b recipe-{debupstream}-0~{revno}
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (native)': native package version may not have a revision
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -i -I -b recipe-{debupstream}-0~{revno} gave error exit status 255
```

It seems to be happening only for Trusty, but I suspect that this is a more general packaging issue. The [`debian/changelog`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~the-warl0ck-1989/xfce-appmenu-plugin/xfce-appmenu-stable-2/files/head:/debian/) contains this entry:

```
xfce4-appmenu-plugin (0.10-1) unstable; urgency=low
  * Initial release (Closes: #nnnn)  <nnnn is the bug number of your ITP>

 -- [Maintainer]  Tue, 15 Nov 2011 14:02:29 +0800
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need have your version X.X-0 or X.X. You should have X.X-1 if this is the first revision of a non-native package.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you suggest changing to `recipe-{debupstream}-1~{revno}`?

Comment: Yes, this or {revno} is empty. Can you show your changelog for this ? from the debian directory, the newest record.

Comment: I added the changelog to the post. Does it contain any clues?

Comment: Well, after trying both suggestions, it failed with [`recipe-{debupstream}-1~`](https://code.launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/experimental/+recipebuild/644247) and with [`recipe-{debupstream}-1~{revno}`](https://code.launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/experimental/+recipebuild/644238).